Sorting Issue in Tableau when apply filter want to sort by most recent Quarters selected in Filter
I am facing a problem  related to sorting data in Tableau. I want to sort sales data in descending by most recent Quarter from the selected Quarter in the Filter. But it is not changing. How to solve this issue?
ss
So i want like if i select 2 quarters or 3 for filtering. it should sort by recent quarter in descending way.
I tried to create some calculated fields like [Sale Quarter] = { FIXED : MAX([Sale Quarter]) }, IF [Is Recent Quarter] THEN [Sale Amount] ELSE NULL END
None of this worked.
As We have Quarters as 2022 Q1 etc. so

Can you sort the table to have most recent Q display first (e.g. Q3 not Q1)? In that case you could a apply a default sort on that column to descending.
